# My Terminal is not working correctly, it is not recognizing even ls command and showing "-bash: ls: command not found " error

Tags: mac, terminal

My Terminal is not working correctly,
it is not recognizing even ls command and showing "-bash: ls: command not found " error, help out in solving this...
I need to work on terminal...

I will be very thankful to u...

~Raviraja

Comment: Are you the root user?

Comment: Yes, Im a root user...

Answer (score 1):

can you echo $PATH and see if it includes /bin and /usr/bin

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply...
it is showing this "PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"...
i think this is not the correct path right...?

Comment: right.. u need to change PATH to include /bin as well as /usr/bin.

Comment: Can u please tell me the way to change the path...
Im very new to Terminal...

Comment: You can use: export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin
It should work.